# What about negative (absolute) pressure in Bernoulli Equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, aerodynamics, bernoulli-equation

I'm studying Aerodynamics and I'm thinking about the Bernoulli Equation Statement.

Ignoring gravity contributes, it states that, in a potential fluid, the sum of static pressure and kinetic energy (per unit of mass) is a constant:

$$P+0.5ρv^2=const$$

Typically, to solve the pressure distribution around an aerofoil (in order to calculate lift) in the context of a potential fluid, we can solve the Divergence problem about the velocity field:

$$\nabla \cdot V =0$$

Once the velocity field has been determined, we can use the Bernoulli equation to find the static pressure value in every point of the fluid field.

So my question is:

If the velocity would be too large in some points of the field, may we find there a negative static pressure? Algebraically speaking the answer is yes, because the Bernoulli Equation may "mathematically" lead to this result. But negative (absolute) pressure has no physical meaning, so how can we know if the Bernoulli Equation application will lead to robust results? A negative pressure would represent an "exhaustion" of static pressure to convert in kinetic energy, so in these conditions the velocity field cannot be realized and the Bernoulli equation would be violated. As I know, if we are dealing with liquid, the occurrence of a negative pressure would lead to cavitation and boiling, but in aerodynamics we deal with air (a  gas).

So, How can we deal with an aerodynamic problem in which such a circumstance occurs, and what are the conditions to garantee negative pressure not to happen?

Comment: Potential flow theory predicts infinite velocities at every convex corner (leading edges of thin airfoils, for example). In spite of this, the predicted forces & moments can be quite realistic - as can flow details away from the corner points. Understanding the limitations of the theories is crucial in real-life applications.

Answer (score 1):

The Bernoulli equation is derived assuming the fluid is incompressible, which is an idealization even for liquids, and even more for gases.

This idealization is valid provided density $\rho$ in the fastest parts of the flow does not change much from its value where $v$ is minimal.

For liquids, this is usually the case. For gases, it depends on the flow speeds. Density of air at points where the flow has high velocity can drop substantially, and so can pressure $p$.

So in places where density of air gets too low, the original Bernoulli equation (with pressure term instead of enthalpy term) stops being accurate. In any case, air as well as other gases cannot have negative pressure, so $p<0$ won't happen.

Comment: Hi, the flow can be considered incompressible as long as its speed remains below 0.3 Mach. Therefore we can say that the validity of the Bernoulli equation is limited by the value of the velocity. However, we could think of a situation where the velocity remains relatively low, but the initial static pressure is so small that it is not sufficient to convert it into the required kinetic energy predicted by the velocity field. Again, mathematically, we would run into negative static pressure. How to avoid this situation? When we solve an aerodynamic problem we never talk about this eventuality.

Comment: The Bernoulli equation remains valid for steady compressible flows. It  states that 
$$
\frac 12 v^2+h
$$
is constant along streamlines ,where $h$ is the specific enthalpy. ($H=U+PV$ per unit mass).

Comment: @mikestone Indeed. And the $U$ term is why speed of the gas can increase a lot without $p$ going negative.

Comment: @tmox if pressure is very low, the speeds allowable for the original Bernoulli equation to be valid are also low. There is a more general Bernoulli equation which 
mikestone pointed out, which takes into account compression of the gas. This is valid when entropy transfer via conduction and entropy production in the gas is negligible (so the compressible flow must be "nice" enough). In places with very high speeds, internal energy per unit mass goes down too, so pressure can still be positive.

Comment: Considering the static air pressure between sea and flight altitudes (for example 10000 meters), it turns out that each of these pressures can be converted into kinetic energy by exceeding the speed of sound corresponding to the altitude considered. Therefore each of these pressures can satisfy the velocity field within the validity limits of the bernoulli equation as presented by me (it is the only one used in my textbook). If I understand your answer, an exceed in pressure drop goes beyond the field of classical applications in aerodynamics and we don't need more general Bernoulli equations.

Comment: @tmox I don't understand your point. Perhaps ask another question.

Comment: My point is how to make sure that the aerodynamic problem we solve does not see excessive speeds that cannot be satisfied by a simple conversion of the static pressure. My books assume that the bernoulli equation for incompressible fluids is suitable for evaluating the pressure field in the fluid dynamics field. So, Let us assume that the hypothesis of incompressibility is satisfied (low speeds), but that the initial static pressure is too low to be converted into kinetics and decreases to zero (mathematically speaking). Would such a problem be beyond my bernoulli equation?

Comment: Still not clear what you mean. If you assume the speeds are low enough to prevent compression, then speeds are low enough to prevent negative pressure.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Lets say you have a flux with static pressure 1 Pa (crazy example, i know)... how you can state with certainty that the speeds that will develops around an airfoil will not be too high to be reach with a conversion in kinect energy of 1 Pa of pressure? That's exacly my problem.

Comment: I would not state that. If the wing is accelerated to a high enough speed, then there would be substantial compression near the wing, and the original Bernoulli equation with $p$ term won't be valid.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, but you still referring to a change in density, while i think that the circumstance we are talking about may occur even preserving a constant density. It simply needs that the velocity filed calculated imposing the divergence of V to be equal zero leads to a kinect energy in some points of the fluid that you can't reach simply with a drop in static pressure. These example don't need a change in density, it just suppose that the divergence problem request a velocity field not rechable by the initial static pressure when converted in kinect energy. May that occur?

Comment: You seem to assume $\nabla \cdot \mathbf v = 0$ remains valid. This assumption then indeed leads to possibility of negative pressures where velocity becomes high enough. But in real gas the assumption fails instead.